# How to display data saved in core data entity on a UITableView when the ".h" file class is UIViewController and NOT UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have designed a camera app and on a press of a button, I want the effect names to show up. I have placed the UITableView but after 3 days of shovelling through internet documentation, I couldn't get the saved records to show up on the table view. I cannot change the class to inherit UITableViewController instead of UIViewController since it is crashing the app. What do you recommend?

Comment: I recommend you fix the issues that are preventing you from changing your view controller's base class. Trying to work around it like this is just accumulating technical debt and you'll just make your situation worse in the long run.

Comment: seek one of the many tutorials on UITableView . https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=uitableview+tutorial

Comment: if you know how to do it when your VC class is UITableViewController, you also know how to do it with UIViewController, except you'll have to write all the code for your delegates (and set your VC as delegate for your TableView in Storyboard).

Comment: I appreciate your opinion, but why all the -ve votes?

Comment: You've probably got down votes because you clearly haven't tried to search for an answer yourself. A simple google search would have yielded a plethora of tutorials/advice. Stack overflow is a last resort.

Comment: `self.tableview.delegate = self`?

Comment: CW0007007, I assure you I don't post questions until I am not able to figure out anything by myself. I have tried for 3 days and failed, which is the reason why I reached out to you guys.

Comment: I'll clarify my question further since many of the people seem not to get what I want.

The major problem is that my application is already working and the main ViewController is a UIViewController. It uses the GPUImage framework to filter the camera stream and display it onto a view. Now I wanted the effects to be user generated. So I built the core data database and populated it with effects data. The problem is how to show it onto a UITableView in the same ViewController so that users can activate/deactivate them on the fly.

I hope I have shed some more light on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is not a lot of work, I would highly suggest to use a dedicated `UITableViewController` for this.

---

***If*** you want to fiddle around the answer to your question would be to set the DataSource of the `UITableView` to your `UIViewController` and implement the `<UITableViewDataSource>` delegate with methods:

```
[yourTableView setDataSource: YourViewController];
```

In your `UIViewController`’s .h file, add:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource>
```

The required methods for your ViewController’s .m file are shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: He will probably want `UITableViewDelegate` as well, depending on what he wants to do with the table.  A `UITableViewController` conforms to both `<UITableViewDelegate>` and `<UITableViewDataSource>`, so if he wants his `UIViewController` to behave like a `UITableViewController`, he'll want both.